# Select onchanged javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 to create a website.
The view has a <select with an "onchanged" javascript function. The function is not being called.
The function:

```
function changeDescription(selObject){
var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex;
var pid = selectObj.options[idx].value;
    alert('changeDescription');  
    let currentEvent = jevents.findIndex((event, pid) => event.id == pid);
    let description = jevents[currentEvent].description;
    let descriptionField = document.getElementById("description"); 
    descriptionField.value = description;
    alert('Descr: ' + descriptionField.value);
}
```

The view (partial):

```
<sect name="event_id" id="event_id" class="form-control" required onchange="ChangeDescription.js(this)">
  @foreach($jdevents as $event)
    <option name="pid" value="{{$event->id}}" id="event">{{$event->event}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

the  is in the layout.app fle:

```
<head>

<!-- Scripts -->
        <script  type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.6.0/dist/alpine.js" defer></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript"   src="..\..\public\js\ChangeDescription.js(selObject)"></script>

</head>
<body onChanges="ChangeDescription.js()">
</body>
```

The controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $events = event::all()->SortBy('event');
        $jevents = JSON_encode($events, false);
        $jdevents = JSON_decode($jevents);
        return view('events', compact(['jdevents']));

    }
```

With more research, I have come up with this:

```
function changeDescription(){
    const chdescr = document.getElementById("event_id");
    chdescr.addEventListener("onchange", function(){
        const idx = chdescr.options[chdescr.selectedIndex].value;
        const pid = chdescr.options[idx].value;
        alert('changeDescription');
        let currentEvent = jevents.findIndex((event, pid) => event.id == pid);
        let description = jevents[currentEvent].description;
        let descriptionField = document.getElementById("description");
        descriptionField.value = description;
        alert('Descr: ' + descriptionField.value);
    }}   <---- red underscore here
```

In the view, the <select now becomes:

```
<select name="event_id" id="event_id" size="" class="form-control">
    @foreach($jdevents as $event)
        <option name="pid" value="{{$event->id}}" id="event">{{$event->event}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

In the layout file:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"   src="..\..\public\js\ChangeDescription.js($this)"></script>
```

Neither of these methods triggers the script.
So, my question is: **How do I get the js script to execute?**

Comment: At the red underscore needs `})}` ... the `addEventListener` is missing a closing `)`

Comment: in onload event  call changeDescription to attach you event listener

Comment: Thank you, Paul T. It is all closed up now.

Comment: -robert, please explain.

Comment: ...so does that mean that it works now, or is there still trouble?

Comment: Still not triggering the script. Waiting for robert to explain his comment.

Comment: OK, I need an event listener, like this:
```<script>document.getElementById("event_id").addEventListener("change", ChangeDescription); </script>```, 
but---where does it go? If in the layout with the other scrips, the element 'event_id' does not exist. If in the blade, where? <Head> and <body> are in the layout.

Comment: Found out that Laravel handles events & listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel will handle events and listeners.
Start here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events